# Lodash like import implementation

Tags: javascript, npm, package, lodash

I am looking for references on How to implement lodash like imports for my module which is a npm package.
Example
in lodash we can import like 
 `import get from "lodash/get";`

Currently in my module we can import like this 
`import {sample1} from "module";` 
but it would be great if we can import like this 
`import sample1 from "module/sample1";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about how you organizing your modules. Place your module under a named directory, place your submodule in that same directory, and use an index.js to re-export.

```js
// import/v1.js
const v1 = { a: 1 };

module.exports = v1;
```

```js
// import/v2.js
const v2 = { a: 1 };

module.exports = v2;
```

```js
// import/index.js
const v1 = require('./v1');
const v2 = require('./v2');

module.exports = {
    v1,
    v2,
}
```

```js
// ./main.js
const v1 = require('./import/v1');
const v2 = require('./import/v2');

console.log(v1);
console.log(v2);
```

A great example can be found at https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/tree/master/src

Comment: For the matter of fact, if you want to use ES modules, use `esm` npm module. Then, execute node.js with a register `node -r esm main.js`

Comment: Thanks for pointing towards UUID. I am using ```rollup``` to bundle my package and made some changes in the config to create separate bundles for each my submodule. I am not able to import them separately.

Comment: my dist structure looks like this
`dist/index.js`
`dist/submodule.js`

Comment: By importing like ```import module from "module";``` I able to import index,js file. But while doing ```import submodule from "module/submodule";```, I am not able to import submodule.js

Comment: I was importing wrong, when I imported ```import submodule from "module/dist/submodule";```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/tree/master/src